# How can I parse non-contiguous elements of a permutation phrase using Parsec's Perm?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Haskell's Parsec supports [parsing of permutation phrases](http://www.cs.uu.nl/groups/ST/Software/UU_Parsing/Perms2.pdf) via the [Perm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Perm.html) module. In the documentation for `permute` you can see how the various permutations "abc", "aab", "bc", "cbaaaaa", etc. can be parsed. While the example shows support for parting many contiguous instances of the same element like "aaaa", it won't parse non-contiguous instances like "aabc**a**", presumably because each parser is included only once in each permutation (the paper seems to imply this in the tree...)

Besides sorting the input so like instances are contiguous, what options do I have for parsing non-contiguous instance?

Comment: Isn't this case for [`many`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:many)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. Could you edit your post to make it more clear?

Comment: @Eric - could you be more specific? The permutation parser accepts empty strings, so a straight `many p` wouldn't work here. I have thought of trying to call the permutation parser on the inputs multiple times, accumulating the results as I go along, but I'm not entirely sure how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you actually want, you may be able to use `many $ oneOf ['a','b','c']`.

If you really need to use the permutation parser, keep in mind that allowing parses of multiple adjacent characters introduces ambiguity. For example, in the string `"bacacbbca"`, it could be parsed as the perms `bac`, `acb` `bca`, or, if you allow repeated characters, `bac`, `acbb`, with a leftover non-permutation of `ca`.

If you allow repeated letters,

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.Perm
import Data.Text
import Control.Monad.Identity

perm :: (Stream s Identity Char) => Parsec s u (String,String,String)
perm = permute $ triple <$$>
  (many1 $ char 'a') <||>
  (many1 $ char 'b') <||>
  (many1 $ char 'c')
  where triple a b c = (a,b,c)

multiPerm :: (Stream s Identity Char) => Parsec s u [(String,String,String)]
multiPerm = many $ try $ perm

main :: IO ()
main = parseTest multiPerm $ "bacacbbca"
```

`main` produces `[("a","b","c"),("a","bb","c")]`.

If not:

```
perm :: (Stream s Identity Char) => Parsec s u (Char,Char,Char)
perm = permute $ triple <$$>
  (char 'a') <||>
  (char 'b') <||>
  (char 'c')
  where triple a b c = (a,b,c)
```

you get the arguably better: `[('a','b','c'),('a','b','c'),('a','b','c')]`.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is a very helpful answer